# Copy all tiff files within a tree to a single location incrementally renaming those which already exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I am trying to write a batch file to copy all `.tiff` files from a directory and its subdirectories and `copy` them to another location. If matching filenames already exist I would like it renamed adding a `_1` to the end of the files name.

I have tried using `ForFiles`, `For /F` and `RoboCopy` but they are not working the way I need them to.

The source looks similar to this, `G:\BLM1\BLMW-0001` with the `.tiff` files and a few other file types. I am trying to copy only the `.tiff` files to the destination of `D:\BLM` without all the subdirectories from the source.

```
@echo off
echo Copying 
echo ".tif files from d:\blm"
echo   "to "BLM harddrive"
echo.
echo Press Cntr+C to abort
Pause
echo.
@echo on
robocopy G:\BLM1 D:\BLM *.tif /Xo /XN /XC /S /MT:8 /R:1 /W:1 /V /DCOPY:DT /ETA /COPY:DT /FFT /A-:SH /XF *.icc *.bmp *.tif.thumb *.oip *.ois *.ojp *.ojs /XD G:\BLM1\Color G:\BLM1\thumb
G:\BLM1\tmpFilename G:\BLM1\undo
pause
```

*Forgive me if this has been covered in a previous post. I searched but could not find a similar scenario.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, this is what you are looking for.

This will do a search for `*.tiff` files in `G:\BLM1\BLMW-0001` and copy them to `D:\BLM`, if however the file exists already in `D:\BLM` it will numerically rename them by adding `_N` at the end of the file, before the extension. So even if you have 5 files with the same name, it will then be numbered accordingly.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=G:\BLM1\BLMW-0001"
set "destination=D:\BLM"
set /a count=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('dir /S /B /A-D %source%\*.tiff') do for /F "tokens=*" %%B in ('dir /B "%%A"') do if exist "%destination%\%%B" (
    set /a count=!count!+1
    copy "%%A" "%destination%\%%~nB_!count!%%~xB"
  ) else copy "%%A" "%destination%\%%B"
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly and is exactly what I needed. Also, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Not a problem. I upvoted but will not show since I am new and rep is less than 15